# Fragment: reloading on back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using Fragments and Activity extended by `AppCompatActivity` in an application.

**Working:**

I have two fragments "Dashboard" and "Order". I am replacing fragment after clicking "Order Button" from Dashboard Fragment, and coming back to "Dashboard Fragment" after pressing back button.

**Problem**

I have called an API on `onCreateView()` of Dashboard Fragment. When I press back from Order Fragment then I come to "Dashboard Fragment" the it recall the API. I don't want to recall the API if I come to the fragment by back press.

Thanks in advance.

**Code to replace dashboard fragment with order fragment**

```
 // Click event of Order
@OnClick(R.id.ll_order)
void openOrder() {
    if (isOrderNotClicked) {
        OrderFragment fragment = new OrderFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment, "Order").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        isOrderNotClicked = !isOrderNotClicked;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting setRetainInstance to true? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29

Comment: I have not tried it, but I don't this would work because the fragment is being recreated not the parent activity Activity.

Answer (score 2):

I did had same problem so i solved by `View view;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        //inflate layout and codes
    }
    return view;
}`  but i dont know it is the best solution
```

Comment: not working. API is not being called not. only static layout is showing.

Comment: It is because it uses if view has been inflated so while adding this fragment every time i instantiate this fragment in your case(Dashboard)

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position, its a good try, but not works correctly